# Using %:p when path has space in it

Tags: vimscript

I have this bit of vim script:

```
nmap <F9> :w<cr>
  \:execute 'silent !tmux new -ds blah'<cr>
  \:execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t blah '%:p' Enter"<cr>
  \:execute 'silent !open_iterm'<cr>
  \:redraw!<cr>
```

It chokes when there is a space in the path with a "no such directory" error. the culprit is the `%:p` bit. How do I fix this?

Comment: You should use `nnoremap` instead of `nmap` here, see `:help :nore` and `:help map` for the relevant help texts.

Comment: Does `'%:p:S'` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
nmap <F9> :w<cr>
  \:execute 'silent !tmux new -ds blah'<cr>
  \:execute "silent !tmux send-keys -t blah '" . fnameescape(expand('%:p')) . "' Enter"<cr>
  \:execute 'silent !open_iterm'<cr>
  \:redraw!<cr>`
```

Comment: The second command is doubling the quotes -- first single quotes in the command and then whatever `fnameescape()` decides to do for escaping -- which may cause problems.